# MIPS Functions and arrays

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, mips

I can understand and use Java/c++ to a good extent, but for the life of me assembly just confuses me there are 2 functions I'm having trouble with. First:

One function that receives a string and prints it on the terminal

And another one that receives a string and converts it to integers (Strings given all made of numbers).

Any idea on where to start?

*Update*

On the second function, so far I got this:

```
main:   
atoi:
    li      $v0, 8
    la      $a0, tstr
    li      $a1, 64
    syscall
    sub $sp, $sp,4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    move $t0, $a0
    li $v0, 0
next:
    lb $t1, ($t0)
    beqz  $t1, endloop
    mul $v0, $v0, 10
    add $v0, $v0, $t1
    sub $v0, $v0, 48
    add $t0, $t0, 1
    b next

endloop:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    add $sp, $sp, 4
```

Updated code, still getting the error on 10 being an invalid operand. And about `sub $v0, $v0, 48` should I just do it as `sub $t1, $t1, 48`?

Comment: Yes, but im still a bit behind that. I Got some parts done but i dont even know how to declare a main, and how to "call" a fuction to use, if i can make myself clear.

Comment: http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/mips%20quick%20tutorial.htm do you know these things?

Comment: Yeah, i know that. What im confused is on do i get an "input" from the user into for example? and how do i from an "input" from the user call certain functions(testing porpuse)

Answer (score 1):

For input-output stuff, you have to use system calls. For writing (zero-terminated) strings you'll use syscall #4, which wants the address of the buffer in $a0. Now just place the umber of the syscall in $v0 and execute it. For example, this snippet reads a string:

```
li      $v0, 8                # syscall number
la      $a0, theString        # buffer
li      $a1, 64               # length of buffer
syscall                       # read!
```

[Here](http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cps104/mips.html) you can find some syscalls numbers.
For the second exercise, here's the C++ code, try to translate it :P

```
int result = 0;

while (*digit >= '0' && *digit <='9') {            // digit is char *
    result = (result * 10) + (*digit - '0');
    digit++;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, there are a couple of errors. First, you're not checking whether you've reached the end of the string (simply compare $t1 with 0 at the beginning). And you should first subtract '0' from $t1, then add it to $v0.

```
next:
    lb $t1, ($t0)
    # are there other character or this is the last one?

    mul $v0, $v0, 10
    add $v0, $v0, $t1
    sub $v0, $v0, 48         # subtract 48 only from $t1, not from whole result
    add $t0, $t0, 1
    b next
```

Comment: Thank you so much, a great place to start!

Comment: So, lets assume i want to print a string, id take that snippet to read a string and then add 
li $v0, 4
syscall
?

Comment: @Zein: no, just replace li $v0, 8 with li $v0, 4, and remove li $a1, 64 (you don't need to specify length)

Comment: how can i post code in the comments whitout it being a line? I got one more question xP

Comment: @Zein: actually I don't know. I tried several times, but... :P

Comment: So far i got the first function done, but how can i "call" it. For example , my program starts, how can i prompt the user to call my function to test it?

Comment: @Zein: sorry, gotta go now, I'll be back in a few hours. Anyway, try reading this: http://jjc.hydrus.net/cs61c/handouts/proced1.pdf

Comment: First function? like a charm!

Comment: Im having trouble on the second function though

Comment: The string given to us contains only int's, so i dont need to check if its an int or not. I dont get the part of the code you gave me,
"result = (result * 10) + (*digit - '0');" 
And no, im not usually this slow <.<

Comment: A string if used the .asciiz will look something like 1|2|4|\n|\0 right?

Comment: @Zein: yeah, right. *digit - '0' converts the character into an integer. '9' - '0' = 9, because there are 9 chars between '9' and '0' ('9' is ASCII 57 and '0' is ASCII 48, so 57 - 48 = 9) http://www.ecowin.org/aulas/resources/tables/asciitable.jpg

Comment: i might be able to make it <.<

Comment: Right, i gave it a shot but im stuck on a loop now. gonna edit my main post with the code i got

Comment: Alright, thanks starting to get the hang of this. Its just such a...HARD language to LOOK at , if you know what i mean

Comment: @Zein: yeah, assembly isn't friendly at all ;)

Comment: whats the operation to check if a something = 0? i forgot <.<

Comment: Udpated code, still the same error, and i manage to ruin your edit on my code. Man im not in one of my brightest days.

Comment: @Zein: sub $t1, $t1, 48 is fine. About the invalid operand I have really no clue about the problem :(

Comment: Phew. my head hurts. assembly uh? :P im going to call it for today. Any chance i can contact you here or any other place for further help into MIPS? You've been a great teacher! and thanks for not writing me the code right away, i love to learn

Comment: @Zein: me too.. actually, I studied x86 asm, I've no experience with mips, but switching between assemblies is easy once you grasp the basic concept :P on this site there's a chat service, we could meet there if you want :)